# Spring Data Elastic Search 4.0.3 - List Of Dates Field

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

Lets say i have I have a list of birthdates

```
@Field(type = FieldType.Nested, includeInParent = true, format = DateFormat.date)
private List<LocalDate> birthdates = new ArrayList<>();
```

What is the proper way to map this using spring data without getting this error..
No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.Long] to type [java.time.LocalDate]

Do I really need to create a custom converter? or a wapper object?
I would think this would be supported out of the box.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to annotate this property should be

```
@Field(type = FieldType.Date, format = DateFormat.date)
private List<LocalDate> birthdates = new ArrayList<>();
```

This would write the mappings entry as type `date` and format `date`, and storing and searching the array would work.

The bad news is that the current version of Spring Data Elasticsearch does not handle this correctly.

The good news is, that I just implemented the fix for this, it will be contained in versions 4.0.4.RELEASE and 4.1.0.RC1; both are planned to be released tomorrow.

**Edit:** both versions are released now